# Keras deep autoencoder prediction is inaccurate

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, theano, keras

I am using a Keras deep autoencoder to reproduce my sparse matrix of `[360, 6860]` dimension. Each row is the count of trigrams for a protein sequence. The matrix has 2 classes of proteins, but I want the network to be ignorant of that initially, that is why I am using an autoencoder. I am following the keras blog autoencoder tutorial for this.

This is my code-

```
# this is the size of our encoded representations
encoding_dim = 32  

input_img = Input(shape=(6860,))
encoded = Dense(128, activation='relu', activity_regularizer=regularizers.activity_l1(10e-5))(input_img)
encoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(32, activation='relu')(encoded)

decoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(6860, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)

autoencoder = Model(input=input_img, output=decoded)

# this model maps an input to its encoded representation
encoder = Model(input=input_img, output=encoded)

# create a placeholder for an encoded (32-dimensional) input
encoded_input_1 = Input(shape=(32,))
encoded_input_2 = Input(shape=(64,))
encoded_input_3 = Input(shape=(128,))

# retrieve the last layer of the autoencoder model
decoder_layer_1 = autoencoder.layers[-3]
decoder_layer_2 = autoencoder.layers[-2]
decoder_layer_3 = autoencoder.layers[-1]

# create the decoder model
decoder_1 = Model(input = encoded_input_1, output = decoder_layer_1(encoded_input_1))
decoder_2 = Model(input = encoded_input_2, output = decoder_layer_2(encoded_input_2))
decoder_3 = Model(input = encoded_input_3, output = decoder_layer_3(encoded_input_3))

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                nb_epoch= 100,
                batch_size=40,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

My validation set dimension is `[80, 6860]`. The problem is if I use the decoder to predict from the test set, my predictions are really off. For example if I predict with the following code-

```
# encode and decode some digits
# note that we take them from the *test* set
encoded_imgs = encoder.predict(x_test)
decoded_imgs = decoder_1.predict(encoded_imgs)
decoded_imgs = decoder_2.predict(decoded_imgs)
decoded_imgs = decoder_3.predict(decoded_imgs)

print x_test[3, np.where(x_test[3, :] != 0)[0]] 
print (decoded_imgs[3, np.where(x_test[3, :] != 0)[0]])
```

a single row of my test set where the values are not zero are-

`[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  2.  1.  1.  1.  1.
  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]`

for the same row, the autoencoder's prediction of the same indices are-

`[ 0.04615583  0.04613763  0.10268984  0.00286385  0.0030572   0.02551027
  0.00552908  0.09686473  0.02554915  0.0082816   0.02254158  0.01127195
  0.00305908  0.17113154  0.01140419  0.03370495  0.00515486  0.02614204
  0.00558715  0.02835727  0.0029659   0.01425297  0.00834536  0.04502939
  0.02260707  0.01131396  0.00561662  0.01131314  0.00493734  0.00265232
  0.0056083   0.01724379  0.06099484  0.03738695  0.01128869  0.01995548
  0.00562622  0.00556281  0.01732991  0.03142899  0.05339266  0.04778111
  0.00292415  0.02264618  0.01419865  0.00550648  0.00836777  0.01139715]`

Now, first I thought, maybe I can use some kind of thresholding to get the 1's from these values. But it seems they are pretty random. For a single row, for the first 50 zero values for my test set, my autoencoder predicts-

`[ 0.14251608  0.00118295  0.00118732  0.00304095  0.031255    0.00108441
  0.0201351   0.00853934  0.00558488  0.00281343  0.00296877  0.00109651
  0.01129742  0.00827519  0.0170884   0.01417614  0.01714166  0.00549215
  0.00099755  0.00558552  0.00829634  0.01988331  0.00092845  0.00294271
  0.01429107  0.01137067  0.01137967  0.01121876  0.00491931  0.00562285
  0.0055124   0.01720702  0.0142925   0.00553411  0.00551252  0.00281541
  0.01145663  0.002876    0.00555185  0.00525392  0.01421779  0.00273949
  0.01698892  0.02529835  0.0112521   0.01130333  0.00554186  0.00291986
  0.00554437  0.01144382]`

How can I improve the predictions? What am I doing wrong here? I must say that the data is hugely sparse. If you want you can download the toy data from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i1qwpaz4gnuj36p/AABYOerIc2tUUqxaDX0tiFjEa?dl=0). Please, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering why you have only 1 encoder and 3 decoder in testing section, since the stacked auto encoder has 3 encoding layers and 3 decoding layers

Comment: How does your loss function look like?

Answer (score 7):

One of the most important reasons is probably your training data size is just too small. You have a fully connected network and thus with 7 layers (including input and output) the number of parameters are just huge, close to 1.8M. You only have 360 training samples. So basically the parameters are untrained.

You can improve your work in two ways. One is of course to get more training data. The second is to follow the CNN example in the later part of the tutorial. CNN has been popular since it can greatly reduce the number of parameters.